# Minimize a function of multiple vector-variables when the function is convex with respect to each vector-variable.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, partial-derivative, convex-optimization

Given $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$, (each $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^m$), we have $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$.

We also know that $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ is convex with respect to each $x_i$ when $x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n$ are fixed.

I want to solve the problem that finds $x_i$'s minimizing $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$.

Hence, I am finding some materials related to this problem.
However, it is too hard to find because I do not know how to call this function.

Is there any specific term that describes this function $f$ ?

- $f$ has multiple variables, each of them is vector.
- $f$ is differentiable with respect to each vector variable.
- $f$ is convex with respect to each vector variable, i.e., for $y$ and $z\in \mathbb{R}^m$,
  $$f(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},\theta y+(1-\theta)z,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n) \le \theta f(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1}, y,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n) + (1-\theta)f(x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1}, z,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n)$$
  with any $\theta\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Intuitively I think that knowing the convexity, you have just to find the critical point, that is the "point" $x=(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ such that $f'(x)=0$

Comment: @Matheman Each $x_i$'s are $m$-tuple vectors, and $f$ is convex with respect to each $x_i$. Thus, I cannot assure $x$ s.t. $f'(x)=0$ is not optimal. (e.g. $f(x,y)$ is not jointly convex although $f(x,y)$ is convex with respect to each $x$ or $y$.) Actually, I consider that a problem that finds the set of $n$ positions in $m$ dimensions that minimize $f$. I assumed $f$ is convex for each $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^m$.)

Comment: I hate to sound cute, but what you call this function is: _nonconvex_. The fact that it is separately convex in each variable really doesn't tell you that much. Of course you can try an alternating descent method.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thaank you. I will try to find separately convex.